# Python Division Programme: Uncaughht Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures

I am Trying to solve this interesting data structure problem,where it expect to develop a code which can do division without using multiplication,division and mod operator
for more about problem you can read it [here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/division-without-using-multiplication-division-and-mod-operator/1#)

`EXAMPLE:`

> `Input:`
> a = 10, b= 3
> `Output:`
> 3
> `Exaplanation:`
> 10/3 gives quotient as 3
> and remainder as 1.

`Logic:`

> As per division algorithm the logic  to get the quotient and remainder
> is by subtracting the `divisor` from `dividend` and keep a record on count
> as counts gives how many successful subtraction from `divisor` to `dividend` can be  performed gives the value of quotient
> and the final subtraction o/p gives remainder
> i have taken the division algorithm logic from this [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCSJp0qlyJc)

`Pythonic Approach:`

```
    count=0
    temp=a
            
    for i in range(a):
     temp=temp-b
     if temp==0:
        count+=1
        break
     if temp>=0:
        count+=1
     elif temp<0:
        break
     else:
        count=count
                    
    return count
```

`PROBLEM:`

> Although the logic is working great when i tested for few cases but as the time-complexity demands to be in `Log(n)` i move the code block in the functions as: `loop` its getting an uncaught run time error

The full code is Mentioned Below

```
    class Solution:
        def loop(self,a,b):
            count=0
            temp=a
            
            for i in range(a):
                temp=temp-b
                if temp==0:
                    count+=1
                    break
                if temp>=0:
                    count+=1
                elif temp<0:
                    break
                else:
                    count=count
                    
            return count
                
        def divide(self, a, b):
            if a>0 and b>0:
                call=loop(a,b)
                return call
            if a>0 and b<0:
                b=b*-1
                call=loop(a,b)
                return -(call)
```

`OUTPUT:`

[image]

Comment: change it to self.loop

Comment: The previous answer fixes the bug in your code.  It still won't get you down to log(n) runtime.  Given your code only every increments count by 1, your runtime will be roughly the same amount of time as your answer.  1000000 // 2 will take 500,000 steps.

Comment: @fmansour `self.loop` did run the code but now the boundation of time complexity is stopping the code Any Improvements?

Comment: Yes@FrankYellin i can see pretty straightforward but can any improvement to this algo can made it to under `log(n)` time complexity?

Comment: If this question for Python 2 or 3? Remove the tag(s) that are not relevant.

Comment: Don't perform divisions by successive subtractions. Don't.

Comment: @user2864740 Python3

Answer (score 0):

Providing you're using Python 3.7+ here's a more concise piece of code for your divide process. Note that this will not improve on performance - it's just tidier:

```
def div(a, b):
    r = 0
    while (a := a - b) > 0:
        r += 1
    return r

print(div(10,3))
```